# Android - Communication between two services in the same application

Tags: android, android-input-method

In an application that I am developing I have a main `Activity` that starts one `Service` (it is a floating window, I am using StandOut library). The same application contains a class that extends `InputMethodService`, I'd like to make them communicate, since I want to handle some `Events` in InputMethod calling methods contained in instances of classes created inside my `StandOutWindow`. I tought to use `SharedPreferences`, is this a good way or are there better ways to make them communicate?

Answer (score -1):

I think you must use `bindService` to communicate with your `service`

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html

To communicate with your `InputMethodService` you can follow this tutorial:

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/04/creating-input-method.html

And to comunicate between `services`:

[Android communication between two services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5744850/android-communication-between-two-services)

Comment: I have tried this, but unfortunately InputMethodService has onBind declared final, so i cannot return the messenger binder.

Comment: There is nothing to post, it is a simple statement. To make two service to communicate you should override the onBind method. Unfortunately, in a InputMethodService it is declared final in its interface, so it is impossible to override it.